# ssrs 2008 sort data based upon parameter value

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

In an existing ssrs 2008 report, I have added a few new columns to the existing report as requested by the user. In addition, the user wants to be able to sort the data on any column on the report by using a sort parameter value. 
The data does not contain any summary values. The columns in the report include:
a. student number,
b. student name,
c. birth date,
d. age,
e. current grade level,
d. attendance code value.

The default value is to sort by student name alphabetically. Whatever field is to be sorted first, the student name will be the second.

I have tried to sort the data at the tablix level and  the row group level and the logic has not worked yet. There is no row group setup right now.

Thus could you show me how to setup the sort by using the parameter value? Would you show how the ssrs report needs to look for me to accomplish this goal and/or point me to link(s) that will show me how to accomplish this goal?

Answer (score 2):

On the row group's Sorting, set the **Sort By** to use the **Sort** parameter to determine which column to sort, like:

```
=IIF(Parameters!SORT.Value = "NUMBER", Fields!STUDENT_NUMBER.Value, 
 IIF(Parameters!SORT.Value = "NAME", Fields!STUDENT_NAME.Value, 
 IIF(Parameters!SORT.Value = "BIRTH_DATE", Fields!BIRTH_DATE.Value, 
 IIF(Parameters!SORT.Value = "AGE", Fields!AGE.Value, 
 IIF(Parameters!SORT.Value = "GRADE", Fields!GRADE.Value, Fields!STUDENT_ATTENDANCE_CODE.Value)))))
```

Set a second SORT to use the `Student_Name` field.

Comment: If I want to use the parameter at the tablix level, how would I setup the logic?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try using **interactive sort**. That way users can sort on any column in the table. In my experience this has worked perfectly well.

Here is more info- (the first section is what i think you would need - Sorting Detail Rows for a Table with No Groups ) -

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc627509(v=sql.100).aspx

Let me know if that was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

1. Select the tablix, right click and click on Tablix Properties
2. Go to the Sorting Tab. Click Add (below the Change Sorting Options)
3. Now select the order or click expression and write an expression to sort the columns based on parameters supplied.
4. Click Ok
5. In the order select A to Z ASC or Z to A for DESC

Comment: What you suggested works fine so far! However how about if the user wants 3 fields in ascending order and 2 fields in descending, How would I accomplish that goal with the logic you just provided? If the logic above would not work, how would I setup the logic to sort some data in an ascending format and other columns in a descending order?"

Answer (score 0):

You need to select each column and select A to Z or Z to A
For example
In the expression, 
IIF(Parameters!SORT.Value = "NUMBER", Fields!STUDENT_NUMBER.Value,"")
In the order column select A to Z or Z to A